# phpspreadsheet set border for all cell in range

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I want to set top border for all cell in range given.  But , the border only applied to first cell from the range. I have tried another type of styling, fill cell colour. It works for all cell in range. Same code has been used for single cell and cells in range

```
<?php
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
 //border
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color;
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;
 $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
 $activeWorksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();    
 $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->getBorders()->getTop()- >setBorderStyle(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK);    
 $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D2:D4')->getBorders()->getTop()->setBorderStyle(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK);    
 
 $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F2')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');   ;    
 $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H2:H4')->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');

 $styleArray = [

   'borders' => [
      'top' => [
        'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,
       ],
    ],  
  ];
 $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J2:J4')->applyFromArray($styleArray);       
 $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
 $writer->save('output_rangeStyling.xlsx');
?>
```

[image: output]

I have tried use `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($rangeTotal)->applyFromArray($styleArray);`, but not work for all cell in range. Is there any option rather than loop to set border for cell range?
thank you.